# how to convert uri image into canvas ondraw method

Tags: java, android, bitmap, uri

I am searching image from gallery and i displayed.now i want to display the images in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`.how can i do this.Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

```
selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"selected"+selectedImagePath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                        img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
```

Here uri selectedImageUri;

My `OnDraw(canvas Canvas)` code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),selectedImageUri);
```

My Error Message

> The method decodeResource(Resources, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Resources, Uri)

Answer (score 1):

The path you get back from the picker is a Uri, and you're trying to load it as a resource id which is an int.  The path returned from getData() is either a file path directly to the file on your SD card or a MediaStore Uri.  If an app saves a file to disk and doesn't use any MediaStore api methods to insert it into the MediaStore db, then you get a file path.  Otherwise you get a MediaStore Uri.  For this reason, I use a wrapper method that determines which it is and returns the actual path:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {    


    String realPath = null;

    // Check for valid file path
    File f = new File(contentUri.getPath());
    if(f.exists())
        realPath = contentUri.getPath();
    // Check for valid MediaStore path
    else
    {           
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            realPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return realPath;
}
```

Once I have that, I load it as a stream from BitmapFactory:

**NOTE** lots of code omitted here, so you might be missing something, but this should give you the general approach

```
    FileInputStream in = null;
    BufferedInputStream buffer = null;
    Bitmap image = null;

    try
    {
        in = new FileInputStream(path);
        buffer = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(in != null)
                in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            if(buffer != null)
                buffer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```